# Mockito, void method with checked exception

Tags: java, mockito

I want to know why i need to handle exception ,when i am mocking a void method which throws exception.

For example

```
public class MyObject {
    public void call() throws SomeException {
        //do something
        }
}
```

Now when i am doing this,

```
@Mock
MyObject myObject;

doNothing().when(myObject).call()
```

it results in compilation error saying

> "error: unreported exception SomeException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

I am wondering , why i need to handle exception for the method, which is itself being mocked .

Comment: You don't need to handle it.  Just put `throws Exception` on your test method.  I mark all my JUnit methods with `throws Exception` as a matter of habit - there's no reason not to.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem When I want to signal that a test is supposed to throw exceptions I use assertion helpers, as for example `@Test(expected = ...)`. I try to avoid the `throws` clause in the test method signature as it does not had any useful information about the test itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you mock an object using Mockito in Java. The framework doesn't change anything to the language specification. And in Java, the `throws` clause is defined at the compilation. You can't change the declared exceptions at runtime. In your case, if you call the method `MyObject.call()`, you have to handle the `SomeException` as in any normal Java code.

Since in unit test, you don't want to handle with things you are not testing. In your case, I would simply redeclare `throws SomeException` in the test method.

Comment: @bohemian it's what we're doing on my project, here in 2019

Comment: @bohemian, we are also doing it this way.
In your case, the exception will obviously never be thrown. If you write like below, then it is thrown.  
`doThrow(new SomeException("Something went wrong")).when(myObject).call();`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with multiple checked exceptions. My code looked something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    public void call() throws ExceptionOne, ExceptionTwo {
        //do something
        }
}
```

and my test was:

```
@Mock
MyObject myObject;

@Test
public void exampleTest throws ExceptionOne {
    doThrow(new ExceptionOne()).when(myObject).call()
    // assert...
}
```

the error message was `unreported exception: ExceptionOne`

The solution was to have `exampleTest` throw both exceptionOne AND exceptionTwo. if you only report one checked exception it's not going to run.